# Apply formula on random sampling without replacement, but with replacement between each iterations

Tags: probability, sampling, sampling-theory, bootstrap-sampling

I am looking for an algebraic solution to explain that I apply a formula on a vector constituted of a random sampling of *n* elements in a population of size *N* without replacement.

The formula is applied B times (bootstraped iteration) with replacement in original populations between each iterations.

If I understood well, I can write that inside each iteration, probability for an element to be sampled *P(e)* is:

[image]

And probability of the whole vector *S* of size *n* to be sampled *P(s)* is:

[image]

But how to explain that between each iteration *B*, probabilities *P(e)* and *P(S)* are restaured to their origin ?

Answer (score 1):

Is it OK to say that [image] and [image] inside an iteration; and that [image] between iteration? And what about *P(S)* ?